# Fast selection of table columns with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, html-table

We have a large HTML table (maybe 100x100 cells). Selecting rows is pretty fast as we can simply select all TDs in a specific TR. But selecting columns with the help of jQuery and `nth-child` is much slower. Are there any faster alternatives for column selection? How about pseudo classes for every column (like class="column-1", and so on)? What is your experience with this?

Comment: I think your solution is good, just be aware that yours Html file will weight a lot more. You gain in javascript performance for loosing in Html rendering.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any faster alternatives for column selection?

I would recommend using the much-ignored [COLGROUP/COL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.1) tags, as per the original W3C HTML spec.  Copy-and-paste this code into a dummy HTML page and see for yourself the magic of COLGROUPs!

```
<table id="mytable">
  <caption>Legend</caption>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="background-color: #f00;"/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1,1</td>
      <td>cell 1,2</td>
      <td>cell 1,3</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>footer 1,1</td>
      <td>footer 1,2</td>
      <td>footer 1,3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

TFOOT tags go *before* TBODY tags.  COLGROUPs have COLs for each column.

The advantage of this is that styling to a COL inside a COLGROUP will cascade to all of the columns in a table.  Background colors, for instance.  It never ceases to amaze me how many people have absolutely no idea of this trick, even though the HTML spec is out there for anybody to read and digest.

Comment: is it possible to add jquery mouseevents on cols. i've tried it, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You can target them, but most table events are going to be triggered from cells.  I only use COL/COLGROUPs for display purposes (background shades for "sorted" columns, for example).  Another helpful thing is applying widths.  COLs with widths will cascade their widths to the THEAD/TBODY/TFOOT columns, provided there aren't any widths on the contained cells that might override them.  In the example above, try adding `width: 50%;` to the style declaration of the first COL tag.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a class for each column. My usual standard is as such:

```
<tr class="row row-1">
<td class="col col-1"></td>
<td class="col col-2"></td>
<td class="col col-3"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `row` and `col` are redundant since you can simply use `tr` and `td` (i.e. will there ever be a `td.row`?)

Comment: sometimes I add the classes to other non-table related elements to simulate table behavior.

Comment: But would $("td .col-2") really be faster than $("td:nth-child(2)")? I doubt it a bit. Does someone have some benchmarks?

Comment: Only thing I could find regarding cons with using nth-child. "nth-child is one of those rather unfortunate CSS attributes that is caught between nearly full cross-browser compatibility, except for completely zero support in IE, even IE 8." src: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the DOM directly?

```
var column = new Array();
var cells;

for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
  tr = table.rows[row];
  column.push(tr.cells[1]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It works pretty fast for me at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/GWqtB/4/ (*for 100cols x 300rows*)

Can you provide an example, so we can see the speed of your implementation ?
Could it be that the delay is at some other part of the code ? like styling while selecting..